# What "place" means in this for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

For starters, this is not my code.

It is something I found online and I am trying to understand what is happening.

I understand for loops and if statements.

However, I do NOT understand what or how "place" in this for loops works, how javascript reads this, etc.

The code is this:

```
for(var i=0, place; i<10; i++){
    if (places[i] !== undefined){
      place = places[i];
```

I am confused as to how
  for (var i=0, place...) works, etc.

Comment: Learn more about the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which is by the way not exclusivelly used with `for` loops!

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop takes the format:

```
for (a;b;c)
    do something
```

Where `a` runs at the start. `b` is used to test when the loop should end. `c` runs each time you go around the loop.

---

In this case `a` is:

```
var i = 1, place;
```

`var` is used to declare variables. In this case `i` (which is also initialized to `0`) and `place` (which isn't given a value).

---

`place` is given values inside the loop:

```
place = places[i];
```

… where the value is one of the places in the array.

Answer (score 0):

places is an array which might be defined somewhere before this loop. and place is a local variable in that for loop

Here, 
'var i=0, place' means  'var i=0, var place= undefined'